# Using Classes with Pydantic to Define Argument Types

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pydantic

I am currently using classes in python to define reusable types with the help of pydantic.

I have a class defined below called User with the attributes id and name.

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
```

I am then using that class in a function shown below. Just to add context, I'm not sure this is the way it should be done (I usually write in Typescript).

```
def raise_exceptions(args:User):
    print(args)
    user_id,username = args.User    

    return user_id,username
```

When I go to test that `raise_exceptions` method using pytest, using the following code to test

```
def test_raise_exceptions():
    response = raise_exceptions(args={User.id: 12345 , User.username: 'test-username'})
    print(response)
```

I get the following error:

```
self = <class 'database.utils.User'>, item = 'id'

    def __getattr__(self, item: str) -> Any:
        """This is necessary to keep attribute access working for class attribute access."""
        private_attributes = self.__dict__.get('__private_attributes__')
        if private_attributes and item in private_attributes:
            return private_attributes[item]
        if item == '__pydantic_core_schema__':
            # This means the class didn't get a schema generated for it, likely because there was an undefined reference
            maybe_mock_validator = getattr(self, '__pydantic_validator__', None)
            if isinstance(maybe_mock_validator, MockValSer):
                rebuilt_validator = maybe_mock_validator.rebuild()
                if rebuilt_validator is not None:
                    # In this case, a validator was built, and so `__pydantic_core_schema__` should now be set
                    return getattr(self, '__pydantic_core_schema__')
>       raise AttributeError(item)
```

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the error and also, how I should be passing that `args` object to fit my current types.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### My Answer

You should study some Python syntax if you want to use it.

1. dictionary
2. keyword argument

Just help you by following if you need some quick example to `call function` and `pass variables`.

### My Example

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str


def receive_args(**args):
    user_id, username = args['id'], args['username']
    print(f'{type(args), args = }')
    print(f'{user_id, username = }')


def receive_user(user: User):  # use `pydantic`
    user_id, username = user.id, user.username
    print(f'{type(user), user = }')
    print(f'{user_id, username = }')


receive_args(id=12345, username='test-username')
# > type(args), args = (<class 'dict'>, {'id': 12345, 'username': 'test-username'})
# > user_id, username = (12345, 'test-username')

receive_user(user=User(id=12345, username='test-username'))
# > type(user), user = (<class '__main__.User'>, User(id=12345, username='test-username'))
# > user_id, username = (12345, 'test-username')
```